# How can a change a choice fields value that is currently set from a workflow

Tags: workflow

I have a choice filed with Yes and No options. In my workflow, I want to change the value from No to Yes after an email is sent. The Set action option does not show the Choice field as an field I can choose to set. The workflow errors out at this step.

Comment: What is the type of the item the workflow is running on? Is it List item, document or infopath form?

Comment: It is a document set